# Получение чистых цифр без запятых и точек без букв Е

Tags: php

Скажите пожалуйста, как избежать вот такого ответа типа "9.999999998E+19"
чтоб было тупо цифры без точек букв Е и +19

```
<?php
    $i = 9999999999;
    $b = 9999999999;
    echo $i * $b; //9.999999998E+19
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь библиотеками с арифметикой без потери точности. Например [GMP](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.gmp.php) или [BCMath](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.bc.php)

Например:

```
$result = gmp_mul("9999999999", "9999999999");
```

Comment: $result = gmp_mul("9999999999", "9999999999"); в $result записывается опять же переменная число которое нельзя перемножать на себя типа $n = gmp_add("$n", "$n"); после того как число достигает своих пределов он функция gmp возвращает ошибку

Comment: @Gradusnik не очень понял проблему. Вам зачем такие числа вообще?

Comment: @Gradusnik до каких пределов вы дошли?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы я умножал очень большие цифры на очень большие и получать очень большой нормальный ответ без Е+ и это всё должно происходить в цикле

Comment: @Gradusnik повторю вопрос: До каких пределов вы дошли? (сколько цифр?) И какую ошибку выдает gmp?

Comment: WARNING gmp_mul(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type on line number 4
0

Comment: Эта ошибка когда я gmp_mul($a, $b); пишу так а с цифрами всё норм

Comment: @Gradusnik Что-то не понимаю я ваших ответов. 1. Вы пишете _"в $result записывается опять же переменная число которое нельзя перемножать на себя типа $n = gmp_add("$n", "$n");"_ - перемножать число на себя можно, только непонятно зачем вы в кавычки переменную взяли. 2. _"после того как число достигает своих пределов"_ - каких пределов? Сколько цифр в множителях? 3. Какая у вас стоит задача? Код и реальные примеры данных можете показать в вопросе?

Answer (score -1):

```
 $i = 9999999999;
 $b = 9999999999;
 echo $res = number_format($i*$b);
```

Comment: :) такой ответ уже был. Вы хоть на результат посмотрите